# How do I emulate enqueuing a Google Cloud Task from inside a Firebase function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

### My code

Hey!
I'm using the Firebase Emulator to emulate Firebase's Firestore, Functions and Authentication. By following the documentation, [Enqueue functions with Cloud Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions), I created a task queue named `removeGroupCode()`:

```
exports.removeGroupCode = functions.tasks
  .taskQueue({
    .
    .
    .
  })
  .onDispatch(async (data) => {
    .
    .
    .
    }
  });
```

### The problem

This `removeGroupCode()` function works fine both in production and in the local emulator. But for some reason it just doesn't get called when I'm calling it **from another function** in the local emulator:

```
exports.generateInviteCode = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  .
  .
  .
  const queue = getFunctions(app).taskQueue("removeGroupCode");
  await queue.enqueue(
    {groupCode: groupCode},
    {scheduleDelaySeconds: 30, dispatchDeadlineSeconds: 60},
  );
  return {groupCode: groupCode};
});
```

> **Note:** The above code also works fine in production, but I still would like it to work in the emulated environment for testing purposes.

### Question

Could it be that for some reason the Firebase Emulator ignores this call because this isn't a feature in the library yet? Or am I missing here?

Comment: If you have a feature request or bug report for the emulator, you can post it as an issue to GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Thanks, I opened one and it was marked as a feature request: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4884

Answer (score 0):

As per above comments

There is a feature request raised for this at [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4884). Which is still open further progress can be tracked there.